# How to concatenate elements of an array into an integer

Tags: java, arrays, int

There is an array say arr with elements

```
6,5,1,0,9
```

I want an integer

```
a=65109
```

and

```
b=90156
```

Comment: Okay, well that seems reasonably straightforward with repeated addition and multiplication by 10. What have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Is it guaranteed that your array elements are single digits? If it is, use repeated addition and multiplication, otherwise string-based solutions are probably easier.

Comment: @user3932092 I posted my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
int arr[] = {6,5,1,0,9};
int result = 0,reverse = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    result= result*10 + arr[i];
    reverse = reverse*10+arr[arr.length-1-i];
}
System.out.println(result);//number 65109
System.out.println(reverse);//number 90156
```

Comment: `result` and `reverse` should be `long` type in case number of item increase in `arr[]`

Answer (score 6):

```
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){
        builder.append(arr[i]);
    }
    long a = Long.parseLong(builder.toString());
    long b = Long.parseLong(builder.reverse().toString());
    System.out.println(a);
    System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: that's pretty smart, because you can just call `Integer.parseInt()` on it and you'll get your number back.

Comment: Also take into account the possibility of the final result being an Integer.

Comment: This will not work, you are concatenating `i` which is the index, and not `arr[i]`, which is the number. So, you will print "1234" and "43210", not "65109" and "90156".

Comment: @FlorentBayle   Opps it would arr[i] let me correct that

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain it by using valueOf() method of String class and parseXXX() of Number class. Example code snippet below:

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
           int[] arr={6,5,1,0,9};
           String str="";
           for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                int x=arr[i];
                str=str+String.valueOf(x);
              }
           int concatenated=Integer.parseInt(str);
           System.out.println(concatenated);
}
}
```

For reverse part do modification in for condition as:

```
for(int i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--)
```

Now the for loop will iterate in reverse order on the array.

Comment: This only answer part of the question, what about the reverse part ?

Comment: @FlorentBayle I posted my answer can you let me know what you think?

Answer (score 0):

In `Java 8`

Code:

```
    List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(6, 5, 1, 0, 9);
    int value = Integer.parseInt(list.stream()
            .map(i -> Integer.toString(i))
            .reduce("", String::concat));
    System.out.println(value);

    Collections.reverse(list);
    int ReverseValue = Integer.parseInt(list.stream()
            .map(i -> Integer.toString(i))
            .reduce("", String::concat));

    System.out.println(ReverseValue);
```

output:

```
65109
90156
```